# OR em join usando Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
Tabela1                Tabela2                               Tabela3                               Tabela4
+----+-----------+     +----+-----------+------+------+      +----+-----------+------+------+      +----+-----------+
| Id | Descricao |     | Id | Descricao | T1Id | T4Id |      | Id | Descricao | T1Id | T4Id |      | Id | Descricao |
+----+-----------+     +----+-----------+------+------+      +----+-----------+------+------+      +----+-----------+
| 1  | Item1     |     | 1  | Item1     |   1  |   1  |      | 1  | Item1     |   2  |   2  |      | 1  | Item1     |
| 2  | Item2     |     | 2  | Item2     |   1  |   2  |      | 2  | Item2     |   2  |   2  |      | 2  | Item2     |
+----+-----------+     | 3  | Item3     |   2  |   2  |      | 3  | Item3     |   1  |   1  |      | 3  | Item3     |
                       +----+-----------+------+------+      +----+-----------+------+------+      +----+-----------+
```

Tanto na **Tabela2** quanto na **Tabela3**, a coluna **T4Id** é uma chave estrangeira da coluna **Id** da **Tabela4**.

Tenho o seguinte linq:

```
from t1 in db.Tabela1
join t2 in db.Tabela2 on t1.Id equals t2.T1Id
join t3 in db.Tabela3 on t1.Id equals t3.T1Id
join t4 in db.Tabela4 on ((t2.T4Id equals t4.TId) || (t3.T4Id equals t4.TId))
where t1.Id == 1
select t4;
```

Preciso obter os dados da **Tabela4** com base nos itens de **t2** e **t3**, mas não é possível usar o `OR (||)` da maneira como eu tenho feito na 4ª linha.
Estou usando Entity Framework.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Você precisa mesmo fazer todos esses joins? Ou a consulta pode ser reescrita utilizando outra abordagem?

Comment: Infelizmente preciso. Mas qual seria essa outra abordagem?

Comment: Não fazer o *join*, começar a consulta pela Tabela4 e não pela Tabela1.

Comment: conseguiu o que queria?

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um exemplo utilizando classes para mostrar como o linq (com lambda) deve ser feito. Você pode mudar o `&&` por `||` caso queira que o resultado esteja em alguma das tabelas, mas não necessariamente em ambas.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tabela1 = new List<Tabela1>();
        var tabela2 = new List<Tabela2>();
        var tabela3 = new List<Tabela3>();
        var tabela4 = new List<Tabela4>();

        var query = tabela4.Where(x => 
            tabela2.Any(y => y.Tabela4 == x) && 
            tabela3.Any(y => y.Tabela4 == x));
    }
}

public class Tabela1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}

public class Tabela2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public Tabela1 Tabela1 { get; set; }
    public Tabela4 Tabela4 { get; set; }
}

public class Tabela3
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public Tabela1 Tabela1 { get; set; }
    public Tabela4 Tabela4 { get; set; }
}

public class Tabela4
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```